Provisioning profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.arkit.main-camera-access.allow entitlement
I was using my "Personal Team" for automatic signing. I was able to run on my device without any issue. then I added com.apple.developer.arkit.main-camera-access.allow into my project.Entitlements file and my project Target's -> Build Settings -> Signing -> Code Signing entitlements has set to MyProject/MyProject.entitlements. But now I cannot auto signing and I'm getting

Provisioning profile  doesn't include the com.apple.developer.arkit.main-camera-access.allow entitlement.

What can I do to resolve this? Please help me.
Thanks

Accessing the camera in visionOS requires an enterprise entitlement that must be requested.

Enterprise APIs are eligible for business use only, and you can only distribute apps that you develop with the Enterprise APIs privately as proprietary in-house apps or custom apps using Apple Business Manager.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionOS/building-spatial-experiences-for-business-apps-with-enterprise-apis
Per Apple

the Account Holder of your Apple Developer Program or Apple Developer Enterprise Program can request the entitlement.

Any apps will be distributed through "Apple Business Manager" or privately for "in-house" use only.

Thanks! do you have an idea how long does apple take to add Main camera access capability to our bundle id after we making the request

@Randi once you request the entitlement you’ll get a file. I put in a request a little over a week ago and still haven’t heard anything.

:(  same,, it's been 4 days for me now

@Randi I let you know when I hear about mine, let me know when you hear about yours.

@Randi 20 days, I just got the approval.

I received it too just now. Cheers!

Were you able to get it to work? for me it looks like not getting any updates here let cameraFrameUpdates = cameraFrameProvider.cameraFrameUpdates(for: formats[0]) else { return }

@Randi I did, it took me a minute but they finally came through. You need the license, and the auto generated entitlements file. You can verify the entitlement on AppStore Connect. I kind of went down a rabbit hole thinking there was something else becuase the docs say “managed entitlement” but nothing else is needed.

@Randi did you ask for permission, run the session and setup the view? You can check the status of the provider too.

Yes! even this CameraFrameUpdates has a value  for await cameraFrame in cameraFrameUpdates {
guard let mainCameraSample = cameraFrame.sample(for: .left) else {
continue
} it looks like it stops after this

And you have a scene running? Like RealityView {} in an ImmersiveSpace? @Randi

oh..should we have Immersive view opened to capture images? I am doing this before I open the immersiveSpace

The scene has to be running, if you check the status now it probably says paused @Randi you can’t use any of the providers outside the space.

Does it need to be full immersive? mine is mixed  .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.mixed), in: .mixed). does it work on mixed mode?

@Randi yes it works in mixed.

Thanks for your help. finally it works :)

You don’t need to be a big company. My friend and I started a two-person company, and I received the required entitlement five days after submitting the Main Camera Access request.
The Apple Developer Program is divided into:

Apple Developer Program with individual identity
Apple Developer Program with organization identity
Apple Developer Enterprise Program

If you already have a company (if you are in mainland China, your business license should state "Limited Liability Company"), you need to:

Apply for a D-U-N-S® Number on Apple’s official website. This is free, and it took me five days to get it (you will need to use your company’s email during the process).
Prepare your company’s website to let Apple understand your business.
Submit an application to register for the Apple Developer Program using your personal Apple ID, and during registration, select “Register as an organization.” It took me five days to complete the registration for the Apple Developer Program.
Create an App ID on the App Store Connect website.
Submit your Main Camera Access request at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=69613ca716fe11ef8ec848df370857f4. If you are using the Apple Developer Program registered as an individual, this page will be inaccessible to you.
After submitting the request, Apple will review it. I spent five days waiting for the review, and once completed, Apple sent me an entitlement document.
Place the entitlement document in the root directory of your Xcode project, ensuring that the bundle ID used in your project matches the one you used during the request submission.
I encountered a minor issue: when adding the Capability, "Main Camera Access" did not appear in the list. I randomly added another Capability and then manually edited the .entitlements file to look like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.arkit.main-camera-access.allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


Restart Xcode a few times, and automatic signing will handle everything for you. (If you haven’t added the Enterprise.license that Apple sent you to the root directory of your project and to the corresponding target, automatic signing will keep complaining). Remember to check that your Bundle Identifier and Team are the same as those used when you submitted the Main Camera Access request.



Thanks for this explanation. when I debug, my code stops at  await arKitSession.queryAuthorization(for: [.cameraAccess]) line and then app is going to background, no crashing nor error. Do you know any reason for this?

@Randi I run session without queryAuthorization, system will show a prompt to ask permission(visionOS 2 beta7), code here:
let cameraSession = CameraFrameProvider();
let worldSession = WorldTrackingProvider();
let arSession = ARKitSession();
try await arSession.run([worldSession,cameraSession])

You don't need to be a business at all to get the entitlement per Apple "the Account Holder of your Apple Developer Program or Apple Developer Enterprise Program" the limitation comes for distribution it will be done through "Apple Business Manager"
